# Run Time Error 1004 for .CurrentPage PivotTable VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba

When I run my code for VBA Excel, my goal is to update a pivot table so that the value of a cell is the filter for an entire column of the pivot table. However, when I do this , I always receive an error:
'Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error.'

This falls on the line

**pf.CurrentPage = val**

This is the entire code:

```
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim pf As PivotField
Dim val As String

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Shortage - Project").Activate

Set pt = Worksheets("Shortage - Project").PivotTables("ShortagePivot")
Set pf = pt.PivotFields("job_helper")
val = Worksheets("Shortage - Project").Range("B1").Value



With pt
    pf.ClearAllFilters
    pf.CurrentPage = val
End With

pt.RefreshTable


Sheets("Shortage - Project").Protect
```

Comment: Likely because your pagefield does not contain an item that equals the value assigned to `val`.

Comment: By the way, you don't the `With/End With` statement, since you're not actually manipulating the object `pt`.

Comment: @Domenic the page field does contain the item that is equivalent to the value assigned to val. The code used to take this value of the val variable and only display results of the pivot table with the pivot field "job_helped" equal to val. Thank you for pointing out that I do not need the unnecessary With statement. This code did used to actually function correctly, but recently has not.

Comment: When the error occurs, what value is assigned to `val`?

Comment: @domenic The val is 00115015, which is the number I had assigned to val by referencing the B2 cell.

Comment: Try refreshing your pivotcache with `pt.pivotcache.refresh` before clearing and filtering your pagefield.

Comment: Same error message appears... I have looked at many other posts about this struggle and none of their solutions work.

Comment: If the underlying values for those cells containing a value such as `00115015` is actually `115015`  but formatted to display `00115015`, you'll get that error.  Is this the case?

Comment: The cells actually contain the values of 00115015

Comment: Just to be sure, when you select a cell that contains such a value, and you look at the formula bar (not the cell itself), you see `00115015`, not `115015`?

Comment: Correct, I see 00115015

Comment: I'll have to take another look at this when I get a chance.  In the meantime, someone else may come up with a suggestion.

Comment: This code, or something very close to it used to work just last month, which is surprising, because now it just doesn't. I do not know if that could be something that could help you.